# Is $(\mathbb{Q}\times\{0\}) \cup (\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty))$ $F_{\sigma},G_{\delta}?$

Tags: general-topology

Is A = $(\mathbb{Q}\times\{0\})\cup (\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty))$ $F_{\sigma},G_{\delta}?$

I started with saying that it is not $G_{\delta}$ because:

Let's say that it is $G_{\delta}$. Then $(\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))\setminus A = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ which is not $F_{\sigma}$. 
But:

$(\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))\setminus A = (\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))\cap A^{c}$ and $A^{c}$ is $F_{\sigma}$, so

$(\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))\cap A^{c}=(\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))\cap\bigcup U_{n}$ where $U_{n}$ are closed. Because $(\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))$ is closed we have that $(\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty))\cap A^{c}=\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ - contradiction.

I thought that $A$ is also not a $F_{\sigma}$ and that the proof would be similar but I can't come up with any. I would be grateful for any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an $F_\sigma$ set. To see this note two things:

1. The union of two $F_\sigma$ sets is an $F_\sigma$ set.
2. Every open set is an $F_\sigma$ set in $\Bbb R^2$.

And this set is the union of an open set and a countable set.

Comment: But why $\mathbb{R}\times\ (0,\infty) $ is $F_{\sigma}$ set in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Comment: The second thing I wrote. It's open.

Comment: Yes but isn't $F_{\sigma}$ set an union of closed sets? I understand why every closed set is an $F_{\sigma}$ set but why every open?

Comment: Every open set is the countable union of open balls. Show that you can write every open ball is the countable union of closed balls. Alternatively, every closed set is the countable intersection of open sets, namely $U_n=\{x\mid\exists y\in A, d(x,y)<\frac1n\}$, then $A=\bigcap U_n$ when $A$ is closed.

Comment: OK, I get it, thanks a lot! :)